# Clarity Datagrid column input filter losing focus on first keypress after moving to next page in paginated grid

Tags: vmware-clarity, clarity

Using a clarity datagrid version 2.3
Seeing an issue where if the user starts typing into the input field of datagrid column filter, the filter input focuses out automatically as soon as a key is pressed.

Since the datagrid is paginated and server driven, this causes the API to get fired as soon as a
key is pressed after the debounce time.

The automatic focus out of the input field cause the filter to only have a single character and the API gets triggered since the debouce is only 800.

Have looked at clarity github for any reported issues, doesn't look like its reported or anyone having similar issue.

**Expected behavior** should be the input focus out should not happend until the user moves the cursor away or presses enter, which is when the debounce should kickin after which the api should be called.

```
HTML:
<clr-datagrid
   (clrDgRefresh)= refreshDataGrid($event)>
...
</clr-datagrid>

TS Component:
debouncer = new Subject<any>();

ngOnInit() {

  this.debouncer.asObservable().pipe(
    debounceTime(800)
  ).subscribe(state => {
     // do something here.. like call an API to filter the grid.
  })
}

refreshDataGrid(state) {
 this.debouncer.next(state);
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/4229 This appears to be the same as this issue, and this was implemented for specific accessibility reasons. We might have to reconsider the issue with this use case in mind to avoid this problem, could you comment on the GitHub issue with some of your use cases?

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm hacking my component, to make sure the focus is not lost on the input field until done so by the user.

```
refreshDataGrid(state) {
   const isClrFilterInputField = document.querySelector('.datagrid-filter .clr-input');
   if (isClrFilterInputField instanceof HTMLElement) {
     isClrFilterInputField.focus();
   }
   this.debouncer.next(state);
}
```

This is still not a clean answer, but as far as I have searched, this seems like an issue with clarity datagrid itself, until I hear from someone with a cleaner answer.

Most likely the upgrade version might have this fixed.
Yet to check that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I think we designed the datagrid to emit the changes on each filter value change with debouncing intended to be done on the app side as consumers see fit.

That said, it is possible to accomplish what you describe. I've implmented a quick and dirty guard based on events but there may be better ways. I'll add code snippets here and a link to the working stackblitz at the end.

You are on the right track with the debouncer. But we don't need to debounce  with time, we only need to 'debounce' on certain events.

Instead of debouncing with time, what if we debounce with an @HostListener for clicks on the filter input? (I'll leave it as an exercise for you to implement a HostListener for the focusin event since focusin bubble's up and blur does not). To do that we need:

1. A Hostlistener that can hear keydown.enter event on the filter input
2. A guard to prevent requests
3. A property to store the datagrid state as user enters text

In general the code needs to:

1. Fetch data when component inits but not after unless directed
2. Keep track of state events that get emitted from the datagrid
3. listen to keydown.enter events (and any other events like the filter input focusout - becuase it bubbles up, unlike blur)
4. Check that the event was generated on a datagrid filter input
5. dismiss the guard
6. make the request
7. re-enlist the guard

Here is a rough attempt that does that:

```
export class DatagridFullDemo {
    refreshGuard = true; // init to true to get first run data
    debouncer = new Subject<any>(); // this is now an enter key debouncer
    datagridState: ClrDatagridStateInterface; // a place to store datagrid state as it is emitted

    ngOnInit() {
        // subscribe to the debouncer and pass the state to the doRefresh function
      this.debouncer.asObservable().subscribe(state => {
        this.doRefresh(state);
      });
    }

    // a private function that takes a datagrid state
    private doRefresh(state: ClrDatagridStateInterface) {
        // Guard against refreshes ad only run them when true
      if (this.refreshGuard) {
        this.loading = true;
        const filters: { [prop: string]: any[] } = {};
        console.log("refresh called");
        if (state.filters) {
          for (const filter of state.filters) {
            const { property, value } = <{ property: string; value: string }>(
              filter
            );
            filters[property] = [value];
          }
        }
        this.inventory
          .filter(filters)
          .sort(<{ by: string; reverse: boolean }>state.sort)
          .fetch(state.page.from, state.page.size)
          .then((result: FetchResult) => {
            this.users = result.users;
            this.total = result.length;
            this.loading = false;
            this.selectedUser = this.users[1];
            // Set the guard back to false to prevent requests
            this.refreshGuard = false;
          });
      }
    }

    // Listen to keydown.enter events
    @HostListener("document:keydown.enter", ["$event"]) enterKeydownHandler(
      event: KeyboardEvent
    ) {
        // Use a host listener that checks the event element parent to make sure its a datagrid filter
      const eventSource: HTMLElement = event.srcElement as HTMLElement;
      const parentElement = eventSource.parentElement as HTMLElement;
      if (parentElement.classList.contains("datagrid-filter")) {
        // tell our guard its ok to refresh
        this.refreshGuard = true;
        // pass the latest state to the debouncer to make the request
        this.debouncer.next(this.datagridState);
      }
    }

    refresh(state: ClrDatagridStateInterface) {
      this.datagridState = state;
      this.debouncer.next(state);
    }
  }
```

Here is a working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-60980488